# Laravel save method taking wrong table name

Tags: php, laravel-4

Hi all i am trying to create a campaign. In the process of campaign i will assign certain products to that campaign. So i have to insert details after post campaign creation into two tables one is `campaigns` and another one is `campaignsproducts`. So i created two models for each of them on the same names.

I am trying to insert records into both tables on post action using save method. I am able to insert into `campaigns` but when it comes to `campaignsproducts` it says `campaigns_products` table not exists.

In my db my table name was `CampaignsProducts`. Please help where i am going wrong. Please find my migration, model and post action code below.

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateCamapignproductsTable extends Migration {

    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('campaignproducts', function(Blueprint $table)
        {
            $table->increments('id');

            $table->integer('campaign_id')->unsigned();
            $table->integer('product_id')->unsigned();
            $table->decimal('product_sell_cost', 10, 2);

            $table->timestamps();
        });

        Schema::table('campaignproducts', function($table) {
            $table->foreign('campaign_id')->references('id')->on('campaigns');
            $table->foreign('product_id')->references('id')->on('products');
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::drop('campaignproducts');
    }

}
```

Model CampaignProducts.php

```
<?php

class CampaignProducts extends Eloquent {

    public function camapigns(){
        return $this->hasMany('Campaign');
    }

    public function products(){
        return $this->hasMany('Product');
    }
}
```

Post action in controller

```
public function postCampaign()
{
    //validation rules for create product 
    $rules = array(
        'campaign_name'         => 'required|min:2',
        'campaign_description'  => 'required|min:2',
        'campaign_startdate'    => 'required|date_format:"Y-m-d"',
        'campaign_enddate'      => 'required|date_format:"Y-m-d"',
        'campaign_urlname'      => 'required|between:4,20',
        'campaign_target'       => 'required|integer|min:1',
        'user_id'               => 'required|integer|min:1'
    );

    $validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), $rules);

    //procee the validation rules
    if($validator->fails()) {
        return Redirect::to('products/newcampaign')
            ->withErrors($validator)
            ->withInput();
    } else {
        echo "<pre>";
        print_r(Input::all());

        //store category data
        $campaign = new Campaign;
        $campaign->campaign_name            = Input::get('campaign_name');
        $campaign->campaign_description     = Input::get('campaign_description');
        $campaign->campaign_startdate       = Input::get('campaign_startdate');
        $campaign->campaign_enddate         = Input::get('campaign_enddate');
        $campaign->campaign_urlname         = Input::get('campaign_urlname');
        $campaign->campaign_target      = Input::get('campaign_target');
        $campaign->user_id              = Input::get('user_id');

        $campaign_id = $campaign->save();
        $campaign_products = Input::get('productid');

        $campaignproducts = new CampaignProducts;
        foreach($campaign_products as $key => $id)
        {
            $campaignproducts->product_id       = $key;
            $$campaignproducts->product_sell_cost = $id;
            $campaignproducts->campaign_id =    $campaign_id;
            $campaignproducts->save();  
        }       

        //redirect
        Session::flash('message', 'Successfully created campaign!');
        return Redirect::to('campaigns');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add this to your CampaignProducts model:

```
class CampaignProducts extends Eloquent {

    protected $table = 'campaignsproducts';

    ...
```

Or the other option is to change your table name when you create it instead:

```
Schema::create('campaign_products', function(Blueprint $table)
```

Comment: i will try changing the name but how to get insert id after i inserted using save method

Comment: i am able to insert it but here is another problem if you see my code there is foreach loop in the end which i am using for multiple inserts but it's inserting only once